# Google Slides - add slide with appscript through Sheets new slide to be added in the end of the presentation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I have this code to add content from Google sheets to Google slides which works great however I want the new slides to be added in the end of the presentation. I am not sure if I could use something like `appendSlide()` somewhere around this area of the code     `let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();`

Now it acts like this...
Title slide, Template Slide, [NEW SLIDE], Slide 1, Slide 2

Desired outcome...
Title slide, Template slide, Slide 1, Slide 2, [NEW SLIDE]

````
  // Replace <INSERT_SLIDE_DECK_ID> wih the ID of your 
  // Google Slides presentation.
  let masterDeckID = "SLIDE_DECK_ID";

  // Open the presentation and get the slides in it.
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();

  // The 2nd slide is the template that will be duplicated
  // once per row in the spreadsheet.
  let masterSlide = slides[1];

  // Load data from the spreadsheet.
  let dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  let sheetContents = dataRange.getValues();

  // Save the header in a variable called header
  let header = sheetContents.shift();

  // Create an array to save the data to be written back to the sheet.
  // We'll use this array to save links to the slides that are created.
  let updatedContents = [];

  // Reverse the order of rows because new slides will
  // be inserted at the top. Without this, the order of slides
  // will be the inverse of the ordering of rows in the sheet. 
  sheetContents.reverse();

  // For every row, create a new slide by duplicating the master slide
  // and replace the template variables with data from that row.
  sheetContents.forEach(function (row) {

    // Insert a new slide by duplicating the master slide.
    let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();

    // Populate data in the slide that was created
    slide.replaceAllText("{{firstName}}", row[0]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{lastName}}", row[1]);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{grade}}", row[2]);

    // Create the URL for the slide using the deck's ID and the ID
    // of the slide.
    let slideUrl = `https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/${deck.getId()}/edit#slide=id.${slide.getObjectId()}`;

    // Add this URL to the 4th column of the row and add this row
    // to the data to be written back to the sheet.
    row[3] = slideUrl;
    updatedContents.push(row);
  });

  // Add the header back (remember it was removed using 
  // sheetContents.shift())
  updatedContents.push(header);

  // Reverse the array to preserve the original ordering of 
  // rows in the sheet.
  updatedContents.reverse();

  // Write the updated data back to the Google Sheets spreadsheet.
  dataRange.setValues(updatedContents);

  // Remove the master slide if you no longer need it.
  //masterSlide.remove();

}```
````

Comment: Do you delete the information in the Sheet after every time the code runs? Or how do you deal with all the duplicates in Slides when a new row is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are dealing with preventing duplicates. However, I  made the test by deleting all the information in the sheet before adding a new one.

Here are some suggestions to add the slide at the end of the presentation:

Replace:

```
  // Open the presentation and get the slides in it.
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();

  // once per row in the spreadsheet.
  let masterSlide = slides[1];
```

With:

```
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
  let masterSlide = deck.getSlides()[1];
```

And also the following change, replace:

```
    let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();
```

With:

```
    let slide = deck.appendSlide(masterSlide);
```

It will work like this:
[image]

**Reference:**

[appendSlide(slide)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#appendslideslide)